# Discord bot disconnects while debugging

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, discord.net

I am writing a bot in Discord.Net that checks online players on the minecraft server, but when I debug my bot and I give the server to it from Discord I have an error: **A MessageReceived handler is blocking the gateway task.** and about minute later bot disconnecting: **System.Exception: Server missed last heartbeat
at Discord.ConnectionManager.<>c__DisplayClass29_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()** and next **Disconnecting** How can I fix it? This is my code:

```
public async Task MessageReceivedAsync(SocketMessage message)
        {
            if (message.Author.Id == client.CurrentUser.Id)
                return;
            await message.Channel.SendMessageAsync("Adding server");
            while (true)
            {
                if ((message.Content.StartsWith(@"\serwer ") || message.Content.StartsWith(@"\server ")) && !message.Content.EndsWith(".") && message.Content.Contains("."))
                {
                    var url = message.Content.ToString();
                    if(url.StartsWith(@"\server "))
                    {
                        url = url.Replace(@"\server ", "");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        url = url.Replace(@"\serwer ", "");
                    }
                    try
                    {
                        IMinecraftPinger pinger = new MinecraftPinger(url, 25565);
                        var status = await pinger.PingAsync();
                        if (status != null)
                        {
                            await client.SetGameAsync(status.Players.Online.ToString() + "/" + status.Players.Max.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        await client.SetGameAsync("Serwer offline :(");
                    }
                await Task.Delay(15000);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can't have a long running task on the gateway thread, else, as the exception says, you'll block the gateway...which leads to a disconnect. Wrap your process in a `Task.Run()` so as to offload it from the gateway.

Comment: So, how to do that?

Comment: Because, I don't know how.

Comment: _ = Task.Run(async () => {
            //code here
        });
        return Task.CompletedTask;

Comment: But there is a new problem after about hour: **16:48:00 Gateway     System.Exception: Server requested a reconnect
   at Discord.ConnectionManager.<>c__DisplayClass29_0.<<StartAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
16:48:00 Gateway     Disconnecting
16:48:00 Gateway     Disconnected
16:48:01 Gateway     Connecting
16:48:01 Gateway     Failed to resume previous session
16:48:02 Gateway     Connected
16:48:02 Gateway     Ready**

Comment: I didn't use **return Task.CompletedTask;** Is it a problem?

Comment: That isn't an issue, Discord occasionally requests a reconnect.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had something similar to this issue.

My discord bot would receive a command and some time in the future, I'd call an independent function send a message to a discord channel. My bot would disconnect and reconnect shortly after, but wouldn't complete sending the message.

The issue occurs when you call await async functions on the DiscordSocketClient like SendMessageAsync. I think calling functions like this when you aren't working inside of a command is the issue. Anyway, removing the await from the the async client function calls fixed the disconnection, thus allowing my